# Show hide Div with checkbox in velocity macro

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity

I am trying to show a div section when checkbox is checked in velocity macro.
Here is the code for checkbox defined in velocity macro

```
<div class="s30">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="_abcd">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="abcd" id="abcd">
                    <label for="abcd">I have seen my <a   href="http://localhost:8075/sample.vm" class="link">current doc </a>.</label>
```

and a div that needs to be shown when checkbox is checked

```
<div id="siri">This is to be shown and checkbox is checked</div>
```

For the above input checkbox, i have defined the jquery as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#checkbox').click(function(){

         $("#siri").toggle();

    });
});
```

When i try using the above jquery, I am not able to select the checkbox. Also the Jquery is not working. I am new to Jquery and any suggesstions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
    $("#siri").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="app1.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

</head>

<body> 
  <div class="s30">
    <input type="hidden" value="false" name="_abcd">
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="abcd" id="abcd">
    <label for="abcd">I have seen my <a   href="http://localhost:8075/sample.vm" class="link">current doc </a>.</label>
    <div id="siri">This is to be shown and checkbox is checked</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#siri").hide();
      $("#abcd").change (function(){
          if(this.checked){

              $("#siri").show();
          } else {
              $("#siri").hide();
          }
    });
  });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```